# Sqlite.net результат запроса в dictionary

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, sqlite3

Есть запрос в локальную базу данных.

```
select * from table_name
```

Делаю запрос через SqliteCommand.ExecuteQuere<>();

```
 var columnsName = cmd.ExecuteQuery<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

В итоге получаю список List с 33 итемами, но они все пустые.

Есть ли способ получить объект Dictionary при получении таблицы? или сформировать сразу Json строку по полям таблицы?